# Action Script 3 - Slide out before next image

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, transition

I have following code:

```
stop ();

import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

TransitionManager.start(axis30, {type:Fly, direction:Transition.IN, duration:2, easing:Regular.easeInOut, startPoint:6});

var nextImage:Timer = new Timer(5000);

nextImage.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playNext);
nextImage.start();

function playNext(event:Event):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

The image slides in but disappears after few seconds. I need to make it stay a bit and then slide out. I've tried it in many ways, but none works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use transition manager?
Let's say you already loaded your iamge into a bitmap or movieclip.. all you have to do is displaying it, after displaying, add an ENTER_FRAME event which moves the movieclip/bitmap to the position where you want it. If it reaches the wanted position, remove the listener, add a timer, repeat.

Comment: Ummm... It was the only way I was able to make it work. I'm kinda newbie with flash.